# How to find $\sup$ and $\inf$ of multivariate sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

I am considering the following problems: [image]

Notice that each of these sets has sequence in two variables, which makes it harder to determine the supremum and the infimum of the sets $A$ and $B.$ One way that I think might be helpful would be to use inequalities so for instance

$$\text{(a)  }A=\left\{\frac{(m+n)^2}{mn}-2:m,n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ Then we could say that $$\frac{(m+n)^2}{mn}-2\geq 2 \text{  (by the AM-GM inequality)}.$$ So $\inf A=2$ and thus $\sup B=2.$ But I am not sure whether this is the best way to approach the remaining sequences.

Answer (score 1):

A few scattered remarks:

1. Note that your proof of $\inf A$ is not quite complete, since you need to show some $(m,n)$ (or sequence $(m_k,n_k)$) that attains (or approaches) the infimum/supremum. If you did this, then you would have realized you made a mistake: your corrected argument would be $\frac{m}{n} + \frac{4n}{m} = \frac{(m+2n)^2}{mn} - 4 \ge 4$, and equality is attained by $m=2$ and $n=1$.
2. More generally you may not be able to leverage AM-GM or some other nice inequality, so one approach is to hold $m$ fixed and maximize over $n$, and then maximize over $m$. For this you might use calculus if you know it.
3. For $C$, you can use some intuition: if $m$ and $n$ are the number of men and women in the room respectively, then $\frac{m}{n+m}$ is the fraction of men in the room. What range can this fraction take, and are you able to approach the boundaries of this range?